# mariaDB ignore database on specific node

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, galera

for a mariaDB Cluster I'm trying to build the following structure:

I have 3 Nodes.
Node 1 replicates database "catalogue" to node 2 and ignores database "addresses".
node 2 has both "catalogue" and "addresses" on it.
node 3 only replicates "addresses".

Is it possible to tell a node to ignore a specific database?
All I've found was this command: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/replication-and-binary-log-server-system-variables/#replicate_ignore_db

It seems, that this only works for the whole cluster, but not a single node?

Comment: See this topic: [filter mysql replication (ignore-db)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830964/filter-mysql-replication-ignore-db). The answer explains how replicate_ignore_db and replicate_do_db could be combined. It might be what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use binlog/repicate-do/ignore; they violate the principle that all the nodes in the cluster must contain the same data and must be able to step in for each other.

When using asynchronous replication between a node in a cluster and some other server or cluster, then those replication limitations may be used.

See [*this*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/) .  About 1/3 of the way down, it discusses replicate/binlog-do/ignore issues.  [*Other notes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera) .

Comment: Looks like replication filter does not work anymore on mariadb galera.

Comment: @shadow0359 - Thanks; I added a reference.